# set SearchView width on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, width, searchview

I'm using the SearchView gadget in my dictionary application on Android but I need to let this searchView fit all the screen width, so how can I set a width for this searchview?

Comment: post some code so someone can help you.

Comment: I used the official sample project "SearchableDictionary" downloaded from Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```